# Multiple apps Codeigniter: remove "index.php/controller" from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I am new to CodeIgniter and  trying to understand the basics and maybe some advance methods to set an MVC based application. After a while I thought i might get a try to set a admin panel as well and created and second folder as admin application.

This is my folder structure:

```
www.domain.com
    --frontend
    --admin
```

In each folder is an app set with it's own .htaccess file. Bellow is the .htaccess file for admin side.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /admin/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]    
</IfModule>
```

Current working url is `www.domain.com/admin/index.php/admin/posts`
and I am trying pointless to change it to w`ww.domain.com/admin/posts`. So how do I remove the /index.php/admin from url.

The `$config['base_url']` is set accordingly for each side(admin/frontend) and the default index.php is set null also , `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Is this the problem cause I have 2 different apps or just a bad configuration?
What is the best practice with multiple applications same site?

Hope i did not duplicated any post and if so please don't hate and try to help me. I am deeply grateful to all of you.

Comment: How many times I have to add its removing "index.php/controller" not just "index.php". Why people don't even read the post and they downvote. i have tried several fixes from those posts and none worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in .htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT 01**

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: I need the $config['base_url'] = ''; to be set because I have css/js files linked in views and the code given was already tested, no effect. Thanks for answer though.

Comment: you need to load css?? So problem with loading CSS??

Comment: There is no problem. I just want to improve the app by removing the index.php/controller. The css is loaded by calling the $config['base_url'] . '/css/style.css'. And by changing the $config['base_url'] I wont be able to get the css/js...I need another solution just with .htsccess or with css path fix ideas also...

Comment: <?php echo base_url(); ?> will get me back nothing so css/style.css is not valid path. that's the way i am using it right now...

Comment: example `<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />`. **No / before css**